# Play video skipping some scenes

Tags: video

I need a (desktop) video player that is able to play a movie and automatically skip some scenes that I define in advance. Is this feature supported in any video player? I looked at Km Player and VLC and I couldn't find what I am looking for.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what this has to do with Video Production, could you clarify how this is on-topic?  It sounds like it is probably a better fit for Software Recommendations.

Comment: This is the start of a good [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) question, but it need fleshed out more. Read [our guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and apply them here - For example, what platform should this app run on?

Comment: Alternately, is there a reason you can't simply edit the video to remove the scenes you want to skip?

Answer (score 1):

This is do-able with the Flash player, or with Adobe AIR which is a great platform for desktop programs.  The video would have to be encoded with cuepoints that were accessible, somehow, to the user. Maybe via buttons that allowed the user to choose which scenes to show or not to show. How much work do you want to do?